# Azure Data Explorer - Track the memory usage of cluster for Queries , dashboards

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

Instead of using the Log analytics , is it possible to query within Azure Data Explorer (Kusto) to track the memory usage for the cluster, Queries and dashboards. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a set of commands (such a `.show queries`) that gives you the system information, including information about queries, commands, metadata changes etc. The information contains CPU and memory usage, see more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/systeminfo)

Comment: Below Query works for me to identify the top 10 memory peak 

.show Queries
| where StartedOn > ago(1d)
| extend MemoryPeak = tolong(ResourcesUtilization.MemoryPeak)
| project StartedOn, CommandType, ClientActivityId, TotalCpu, MemoryPeak
| top 10 by MemoryPeak

Answer (score 0):

I was also interested in cluster memory utilization. The best I could do was to query Log Analytics for the peak memory usage of queries and commands and plot the sum of overlapping intervals. This is obviously overestimated since the query most likely doesn't have peak memory usage all the time but it's as close as you can get in monitoring cluster memory pressure:

```
let from_ = now(-14d);
let to_   = now();
let MemoryConsumption = ADXCommand
| project StartedOn, EndedOn=StartedOn+totimespan(Duration), PeakMemory=tolong(ResourceUtilization.MemoryPeak)
| union (
    ADXQuery | project StartedOn, EndedOn=StartedOn+totimespan(Duration), PeakMemory=MemoryPeak
  );
let query_starts = (MemoryConsumption | project delta =  PeakMemory, TimeUtc = StartedOn);
let query_ends =   (MemoryConsumption | project delta = -PeakMemory, TimeUtc = EndedOn);
union query_starts, query_ends
| make-series delta = sum(delta) on TimeUtc from from_ to to_ step 2s
| mv-apply  delta to typeof(long), TimeUtc to typeof(datetime) on (project max_memory = row_cumsum(delta), TimeUtc)
| summarize max_memory=avg(max_memory) by bin(TimeUtc, 15m)
| render timechart with (xcolumn=TimeUtc, ycolumns=max_memory)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can visualize the memory usage of commands and queries with the following kusto query:

```
.show commands-and-queries 
| where StartedOn > ago(1d) 
| summarize memorySum=sum(MemoryPeak) by bin(StartedOn, 5m)
| render linechart
```